Multilayer Denoise does not work
I'm trying to multilayer Denoise a shot but can't for the life of me figure out what I'm doing wrong. I followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cQkLakQKaT0 step by step and double and triple checked everything. The image I'm getting is not completely opaque like for example 50% of the cap is transparent and the dark parts of the sky too and the Brightness in the whole picture is off (I suspect because of the transparency).
I sadly can't share the project file as it contains confidential stuff for an unreleased product but I'm happy to share more screenshots on request. Any Idea is welcome and appreciated.
Image Denoised using the standard method 

Image Denoised using the Multilayer method 
I just realised that the Picture is completely transparent when I save it. The Preview on top of the Render Layer shows this too but the Viewer Node does show an image in the compositor
Screenshot of the Node Setup 

Screenshot of the Tutorial 

